# Deleting row in R based on meeting conditions

Tags: r, row, conditional-statements, delete-row

I am reading in a very large dataset using read.table.  Once I've read the data in, I want to keep only those records that fall in a certain lat/lon region.  So basically I want to define upper and lower bounds on $Lat and $Lon, and discard all other rows.   I'm sure this is a fairly easy operation, but I am new to R coding and want to make sure I find the most elegant approach.  Here is my code to read in the data:

```
#trackfilenums=1:96   #these are the legs of the track files
trackfilenums=1

for(i in trackfilenums){

print(paste(i, 96, Sys.time(), sep=" : "))
track.data.file <- paste('input/track_param/track_param_',zpad(i,4),'.txt', sep="")
track.data <- read.table( track.data.file ,fill=TRUE,as.is=TRUE,skip=1)
sel <- !is.na(track.data[,9])
track.data <- track.data[sel,]
colnames(track.data) <- c("ID", "Hr", "Lon", "Lat", "UT", "VT", "LandFlag", "ET", "CP", "Penv", "Rmax", "Vmax", "X1", "N", "EOF1", "EOF2", "EOF3", "EOF4", "Angle", "MPI", "Filling.alpha", "Filling.beta", "Filling.gamma")

## keep all points 
track.data<-track.data[,c("ID", "Hr", "Lon", "Lat", "UT", "VT", "LandFlag", "ET", "CP", "Penv", "Rmax", "Vmax", "X1")]

}
```

Instead of that last part where I keep all track points, I'd like to only keep lat between 30 and 35, and lon between 128 and 140.

Comment: Simply subset rows according to those conditions.

Comment: could you describe the syntax of the subset code?  THanks!

Comment: I used track.data.sub <- subset(track.data, Lon>=128 & Lon<=140 & Lat>=30 and Lat<=35)

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're looking for is row-selection rather than row-deletion.  You can select rows by using AND gate logic with your four criteria:

```
# Note that I am using the 'attach' function to
# make things a little easier to read.
attach(track.data)
track.data[Lat >= 30 & Lat <=35 & Lon >=128 & Lon <= 140,]
detach(track.data)
```

This tells your data frame to select rows that meet all of the four criteria.

**Update**: As requested, here is the same code in 'subset' form:

```
subset(track.data, Lat >= 30 & Lat <=35 & Lon >=128 & Lon <= 140)
```

Comment: Please do not use `attach`. Look at `?subset`.

Comment: @Roland As I noted, it is purely to make the example readable (while retaining as much of the OP's original approach as possible).  I prefer not to use 'attach' or 'subset' at all, since I lean towards vector maths but attach does get the point across for this example.  I can add the subset code as an example as well.